# Ant script to build my app by specifying different server through command line

Tags: android, ant, android-build

I have developed an Android app, which communicates with a server. I have 2 servers. One is for **development**, the other one is for **production**.

In my Android source code, I have to manually change the **server URL** when make a build.

For example:
for **debug mode release**, I use:

```
String url = "http://develop/service"
```

for **production release**, I use:

```
string url = "http://production/service"
```

The `url` variable is passed to request sending function like `sendReqToServer(url);` .

I am tired of making manual change on this url change for different release. Instead, I would like to use **Ant script** to specify the `url` by using a command line when making different release build , something like `ant release-develop` (use development server) & `ant release-product` (use production server).

To achieve this, I think in **build.xml** I need to create `<target name="release-develop">` & `<target name="release-product">`. but I am not sure how to make the ant script to specify the url for my app through command line?

Could someone please provide me more detailed information about how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you extract the two urls into two properties files, and in the two ant targets, copy the right one to the target directory? / UPDATE for the replacement check pepuch's answer, however, if you replace token with actual url before compiling, you still need to restore the url back to token after compiling. So I recommend the second way in the answer.

Comment: Hi, Coolcfan, thanks, your suggestion sounds good, could you please provide with more details. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace` task to override/replace url. It will look like this:

```
<target name="release-product">
    <replace file="path to your *.java class which contains url" token="@URL@" value="http://production/service">
    <!-- compile app -->
</target>

<target name="release-develop">
    <replace file="path to your *.java class which contains url" token="@URL@" value="http://develop/service">
    <!-- compile app -->
</target>
```

This is not the best solution because you will need to change your source code. Better will be to create config file from which you will read url. In this case it will look like this:

YourUrlClass.java

```
String url = Config.getUrl(); // get Url method will read url from config file
```

Appconfig.ini

```
url=http://develop/service
```

build.xml

```
<target name="release-product">
    <echo file="appconfig.ini" override="true">url=http://product/product</echo>
    <!-- compile app using appconfig.ini -->
</target>

<target name="release-develop">
    <echo file="appconfig.ini" override="true">url=http://develop/product</echo>
    <!-- compile app using appconfig.ini -->
</target>
```

Of course you don't need to create appconfig.ini file using `<echo/>` task. The idea is that you can override `appconfig.ini` file using different version.

Comment: Override appconfig.ini file using different version of what? different version of files? Do you mean I have to create separate appconfig.ini files, one contain development url & one contains production url, then override a default appconfig.ini to one of the file? If, so where should I put these files?

Comment: You should create class that will read app configuration from 'some' config file. Place it whereever you want. The idea is that you should read configuration from this file and override this file while building product.

Comment: According to my previous comment. You can place your config file in some place on disk/server. In that case you won't need to recompile application to change url. You can also place config file in compiled *.jar/*.war.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probaby go with config files like other answers, but here's another possibility that I usually do to only log for development builds :

```
if( BuildConfig.DEBUG  )
{
    //set develop
}
else
{
    //set release
}
```

This BuildConfig.DEBUG is set based on if its compiled in debug or release mode.

Answer (score 0):

you may use a property `${url}` in all targets that need the server url :

```
<target name="release">
 <echo> Deployment => ${url} started !</echo>
 ...
</target>
```

and start your antfile via :

```
ant -f yourfile.xml -Durl=http://develop/service
```

or

```
ant -f yourfile.xml -Durl=http://production/service
```

If you have more specific properties, create a propertyfile for every deploytarget and in your antfile use :

```
<property file="/config/${deploymode}.properties"/>
```

afterwards start your antfile via :

```
ant -f yourfile.xml -Ddeploymode=test
```

or

```
ant -f yourfile.xml -Ddeploymode=production
```